# Github Flutter Login

Tags: flutter

[Github API](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) specifies that redirect url is required in order to get the login result of the authorization. But if I am developing a non hybrid flutter app without using webviews. How would I redirect the user to come back to the app after prompting user to login using things like [URL Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth

code snippet

```
final simpleAuth.GithubApi githubApi = new simpleAuth.GithubApi(
      "github", "clientId", "clientSecret", "redirect:/",
      scopes: [
        "user",
        "repo",
        "public_repo",
      ]);

void login(simpleAuth.AuthenticatedApi api) async {
    try {
      var success = await api.authenticate();
      showMessage("Logged in success: $success");
    } catch (e) {
      showError(e);
    }
  }
... 
ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.launch),
            title: Text('Login'),
            onTap: () {
              login(githubApi);
            },
          ),
ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () {
              logout(githubApi);
            },
          ),
```

full example code 
https://github.com/Clancey/simple_auth/blob/master/simple_auth_flutter_example/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on how to add github login to flutter: https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-firebase-github-authentication-in-flutter-1c49a172c648

Add these as dependencies:

```
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  uni_links: ^0.2.0
  http: ^0.12.0+1
```

canLaunch redirects you to the url where the user can sign in to github.Then getLinksStream waits fore the redirect.  There you get a link with a code. This code is used to send a post request to github.With the response you can retrieve your user. Everything is explained thoroghly in the mentioned tutorial.

```
 String url = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize" +
      "?client_id=" +
      "${yourClientId}" +
      "&scope=public_repo%20read:user%20user:email";

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(
      url,
      forceSafariVC: false,
      forceWebView: false,
    );

    getLinksStream().listen((link) {
           String code = link.substring(link.indexOf(RegExp('code=')) + 5);
  final response = await http.post(
    "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: jsonEncode(GitHubLoginRequest(
      clientId: "${yourCredentialId},
      clientSecret: ${yourClientSecret},
      code: code,
    )),
  );
    }, cancelOnError: true);
```

Comment: do you get redirected to your app after successfully logging into GitHub? (after getting this on your browser: https://appname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?code=)

I am facing the issue that redirection is not being caught by my app as I’ve set the deep link configuration in Step 4 & 5 of that article.

Can you show me your <intent-filter> in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Yes, I get redirected to my app. Here is my Intent-filter. Auth is "auth" and i did not change it. "projectfinder" is my app name.

`<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                        android:host="auth"
                        android:scheme="projectfinder" />
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: auth is the link which is displayed on the firebase GitHub sign-in method? right?

Comment: I did not put the link from the sign in method there. I have just let it stay `host="auth"`

Comment: It doesn't work, can you look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61301801/11545939